# Flutter toggle switch and shared preferences

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to save the state of the toggle switch in my app and load it at the start. For that I use `SharedPreferences`:

```
Future<bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
  return prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
}

Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");
  print(isSwitchedFT);

  return isSwitchedFT;
}
```

The saveSwitchState() runs every time when I change the toggle value.

The problem is at the start of the app.
I created a bool value: `bool isSwitchedFT = false;`
I initialize with false because null gives me errors.
How would I set `isSwitchedFT = getSwitchState;`
On empty value for isSwitchedFT it compiles but I get a red error on my emulator:

```
'package:flutter/src/material/toggleable.dart': Failed assertion: line 45 pos 15: 'tristate || value
 != null': is not true.
```

when compiled with a value the switch works fine an saves the changing value.

```
Switch(
  value: isSwitchedFT,
  onChanged: (bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isSwitchedFT = value;
      saveSwitchState(value);
      print('Saved state is $isSwitchedFT');
      //switch works
    });
    print(isSwitchedFT);
  },
  activeTrackColor: Color(0xFF1D1F33),
  activeColor: Colors.purple[500],
),
```

The thing I want is to load the app with the last value of the switch.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a `StatefulWidget`? If so, you can use `initState` to get the data and set it to the value which `Switch` is using. Show your full code in a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this code for Sample

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isSwitchedFT = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getSwitchValues();
  }

  getSwitchValues() async {
    isSwitchedFT = await getSwitchState();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
    print('Switch Value saved $value');
    return prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
  }

  Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");
    print(isSwitchedFT);

    return isSwitchedFT;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Switch(
              value: isSwitchedFT,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSwitchedFT = value;
                  saveSwitchState(value);
                  print('Saved state is $isSwitchedFT');
                  //switch works
                });
                print(isSwitchedFT);
              },
              activeTrackColor: Color(0xFF1D1F33),
              activeColor: Colors.purple[500],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked on the first try. App loads with the value it had on exit. Now i have another problem. I have logic in my main.dart that checks the state of a switch. But isSwitchedFT is now local. Do I use a getter method to retrieve the value for the main.dart? Complete noob question i know. An thank for the fast responses!

Comment: isSwitchedFT declared  local is  for your convenience you can directly return the value  from the getter

Comment: spoke too soon after trying on my real android device and iOS simulator I get : ═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dependencies: [MediaQuery, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#20e6f], Directionality]):
'package:flutter/src/material/toggleable.dart': Failed assertion: line 221 pos 12: 'tristate || value != null': is not true.

Comment: change the value of switch from isSwitchedFT to isSwitchedFT ?? false , written the code below Switch(
              value: isSwitchedFT ?? false

Comment: After a few restarts and reinstall it works great. ty. Now I am trying to learn about getter/setters to get this value to MyHomePage class. There is some logic that needs to know the value of isSwitchedFT. Any tips pointers to some videos/articles?

Comment: This is actually different question  that you asked, but for you I can provide a link for getter setters https://youtu.be/yzQkSwXkjgg refer this for basics

Comment: If you have got the desired answer Upvote for the answer so that it would be helpful for others.

Comment: I can't. My reputation is still too low. Just added the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is load the SharedPreferences and set your isSwitchedFT on the init state. But because you need an async and await, you need to do it on a separate method (I would also advise you to instantiate SharedPreferences only once and then re-use it like I've done below):

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

@override
void initState() {
  loadSharedPreferencesAndSwitchState();
  super.initState();
}

void loadSharedPreferencesAndSwitchState() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. Can't try it out right now. 
The structure of the project is made up of:

- main.dart
- switch.dart
- jsonLogic.dart

main.dart has both a stateles and statefull widgets.
In the statefull widget I call the switch.dart and the json parts.

The initialization of the isSwitchedFT happens in the main file.
Looks like it should be brought to the switch.dart file
here is the full switch.dart file w/out the imports:

```
class SwitchIt extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwitchItState createState() => _SwitchItState();
}

class _SwitchItState extends State<SwitchIt> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Switch(
          value: isSwitchedFT,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              isSwitchedFT = value;
              saveSwitchState(value);
              print('Saved state is $isSwitchedFT');

              //switch works
            });
            print(isSwitchedFT);
          },
          activeTrackColor: Color(0xFF1D1F33),
          activeColor: Colors.purple[500],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

Future<bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
  return prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
}

Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");
  print(isSwitchedFT);
  return isSwitchedFT;
}
```

Maybe the solution is already posted. Can't check now. But the idea is to bring isSwitchedFT to switch.dart and use initState() to set its value from shared_preferences.