# Flutter SharedPreferences unable to get/set updated value

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, setter, getter

I save a switch bool value in the switch file. Using the shared_preferences save it on exit. The problem was solved here: [Using shared_preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456086/flutter-toggle-switch-and-shared-preferences)

My code now:

```
class SwitchIt extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SwitchItState createState() => SwitchItState();
}

class SwitchItState extends State<SwitchIt> {
  bool isSwitchedFT = false;
  // bool getIsSwitchedFTresult;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSwitchValues();
  }

  getSwitchValues() async {
    isSwitchedFT = await getSwitchState();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
    print('Switch Value saved $value');
    return prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
  }

  Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");
    print(isSwitchedFT);

    return isSwitchedFT;
  }

  void loadSharedPreferencesAndSwitchState() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");
  }

  bool get getIsSwitchedFT {
    return isSwitchedFT;
  }

  set getIsSwitchedFT(bool value) {
    isSwitchedFT = value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Switch(
          value: isSwitchedFT,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              isSwitchedFT = value;
              saveSwitchState(value);
              print('Saved state is $isSwitchedFT');

              //switch works
            });
            print(isSwitchedFT);
          },
          activeTrackColor: Color(0xFF1D1F33),
          activeColor: Colors.purple[500],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In the main.dart I access this:

```
  get getIsSwitchedFTresult {
    return SwitchItState().getIsSwitchedFT;
  }
```

Just to see what is the returned value I have:

```
Container(
  child: Text(getIsSwitchedFTresult.toString()),
  ),
```

The returned value depends on the value I initialized in the  beginning of SwitchItState class

```
class SwitchItState extends State<SwitchIt> {
  bool isSwitchedFT = false;...
```

returns "false"

```
bool isSwitchedFT = true;
```

returns "false"

```
bool isSwitchedFT;
```

returns "null"

**So it looks it returns the initial that I initialize it too.
The thing I want is it to return the current value the switch is in now or the position the user left it in before closing the app. But it always uses the value that is hardcoded.
I even used a Future.delayed by 3 seconds. (hoping the value needed time to update). Same result**
This is the part of my code I need it in:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (getIsSwitchedFTresult == true &&
```

This is a small excerpt of my code in main.dart. Depending on the value of the code I have set up a notification to go out. This is working. I only am telling this to show the overall functionality of the app.

Comment: When you do `SwitchItState().getIsSwitchedFT` you are instantiating a new instance of your `SwitchItState` class. It will always return you the default value when you call the method. You should either retrieve the value from `SharedPreferences` when you need it in a different class, or store in your State Management solution to be available everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So a state management system needs to be added to do this? I thought setter/getters are the only thing I need here. Just can't write them properly

Comment: It's not necessarily the only way, just one of the possibilities. You could pass the variable through the `Navigation` as you move from route to route, or you could use a `Provider`. Try exploring a bit more and see what fits your solution.

Comment: Big thanks. New to this so yeah I will watch some tutorials and learn which solution I can use.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Switch doesn't get updated is because while `Future<bool> getSwitchValues()` is called on initState, the value it returns was never assigned to the Switch.

To solve this issue, set the returned bool value to the Switch.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  /// Fetch bool switchState from SharedPreferences
  getSwitchValues().then((bool switchState) {
    setState(() {
      /// Switch active state will be updated
      isSwitchedFT = switchState;
    });
  });
}
```

Here's a minimal repro.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var isSwitchedFT = false;
  final sharedPrefSwitchState = 'sharedPrefSwitchState';


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSwitchState().then((bool switchState) {
      setState(() {
        isSwitchedFT = switchState;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
    var pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getBool(sharedPrefSwitchState) ?? false;
  }

  Future<void> saveSwitchState(bool active) async {
    var pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setBool(sharedPrefSwitchState, active);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Switch(
          value: isSwitchedFT,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              isSwitchedFT = value;
              saveSwitchState(value);
              debugPrint('Saved state is $isSwitchedFT');
            });

            debugPrint('$isSwitchedFT');
          },
          activeTrackColor: Color(0xFF1D1F33),
          activeColor: Colors.purple[500],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]